# C3p0 specify max and min Idle connections

Tags: java, mysql, database, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

DBCP let's you specify a min and max number for Idle connections [See Link](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html)

I can't find a similar option in C3p0. I can specify a max and min pool size, but that appears to be it. Is there a way to specify this in C3p0? If not, does anyone know if C3p0 has a default for max/min idle connections, or does it not limit them?

Answer (score 1):

As I know c3p0 limits *time* before unused connection being expired.
This time is configured with maxIdleTime parameter.

Comment: Helpful answer, but I am looking specifically for min and max idle connections.